# bitbake failed with ExpansionError

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, imx7

**Context:**

I'm following the [NXP i.MX7 Reference](http://www2.keil.com/mdk5/ds-mdk/imx7reference) to build a Linux image for the i.MX 7 SABRE board. This process went smoothly, and I was successful in building and loading the krogoth image on the board. The problem arise when I tried to add the [openembedded-core](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/krogoth/layer/openembedded-core/) layer to my image. I immediately get the error below. I included my *bblayers.conf* for reference. Any help would be appreciated. I don't even need sqlite, so if there's a way to bypass it, then that would be fine.

**Error:**

```
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /fsl-community-bsp-platform/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-support/sqlite/sqlite3_3.16.2.bb: Failure expanding variable SQLITE_PV, expression was ${@sqlite_download_version(d)} which triggered exception TypeError: getVar() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

**bblayers.conf**

```
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BSPDIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/../..')}"

BBFILES ?= ""
BBLAYERS = " \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-poky \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/openembedded-core/meta \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-arm \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-arm-extra \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-fsl-demos \
"
```

The only difference between a successful build, and a failling build is the line: `${BSPDIR}/sources/openembedded-core/meta`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't add `openembedded-core/meta` to your `bblayers.conf`!

In your list, `BBLAYERS =`, the two entries

```
${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
${BSPDIR}/sources/openembedded-core/meta \
```

are both the same layer. `meta` in `Poky`, is taken directly from `OpenEmbedded`. The `Poky` repository is combined from multiple upstream repositoris using a script, `combo-layer`. (Which in my opinion is unfortunate, though I can see why it's being done).

If you wan't e.g. a newer version of `meta`, you need to update `poky`, or remove `poky` completely, and download `openembedded-core` and `bitbake` separately.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience building BSP with yocto, specifically with NXP imx7, I have got ExpansionError very frequent. Most of the time, I found out that there is redundant package or layer or recipe in some cases. Once you remove them from installation, It works smooth.

In your case, Just remove following from the build and It should be fine.

```
${BSPDIR}/sources/openembedded-core/meta \
```